# In Android, how to have bi-directional scroll AND show both scroll bars?

Tags: android

It seems that Android ScrollView does not support bi-directional scroll.  Although, a HorizontalScrollView can be placed inside a ScrollView, which effectively provides bi-directional scrolling (as below).

However, the horizontal scrollbar is now "at the bottom of" the vertical scroll view. So, if I scroll all the way to the bottom of the vertical scroll view, and then drag left to right, the horizontal scrollbar will show.  Otherwise, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't show, because it is "off the screen".

Any advice?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalscrollview"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/pagepane"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
           </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Don't you need the views within the scrollviews to exceed their parents height and/or width? As I see it you've got everything set to fill_parent, so no scrollbars are ever going to be needed...

Comment: Sorry, should've specified, I am programmatically adding custom views to the LinearLayout, their width and heights exceed the scrollviews.  It does scroll horizontally and vertically, but the horizontal scrollbar is not displayed.